# Store objects received from API in app's DB or always fetch from API?

Tags: asp.net-core, synchronization, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am using API of the payment gateway which is used by our ASP.NET Core app to retrieve the history of customer's payments when they open the "Payments" page.

The question is this a good practice to always retrieve this info from the payment service's API or is it better to store a local copy of these objects, since this will be faster?

things to consider:

- payment objects are not modified in the API once they are completed
- retrieving directly from API affects the allowed request limit for that API
- to store these objects locally I think I need to sync my DB table with API's data regularly

P.S.: The stack I am using:

- backend: ASP.NET Core
- database: PostgreSQL
- payment gateway: Stripe

Comment: I suggest to checkout a bit about [Write through and write back](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-through-and-write-back-in-cache/) when implementing cache, Implement them as Memory cache or Redis cache as usecases required

Comment: Use some sort of logic with [GetOrCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0), have some logic to organize and remove cache key as needed should be enough

Comment: I see it differently. Customer's payments history should always be correct, if you save a copy as the cache, how to ensure the latest payment history to be updated? Or you have another api which is wise enough to just call for the latest part and then update the local data? So I think it's better to call api all the time, and try to improve the api's performance. It's just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it completely depends on your scenario
If you use the api. The only problem is that your server uses a lot of bandwidth in high number of requests, and things like latency may not be pleasant for your users. In general, it is better to have a copy in your database, even if that API server is out of reach Your application will not have any problems and will work properly